# I am stuck in how to use the return output of a function into another function

Tags: python, data-analysis

I want to use the result of a function in another function to do comparison and print out the balance. But the code is repeating itself twice and not giving me the required result

Below is part of the code

```
def coins():
    print("Please insert coins.")
    qtrs = int(input('How many quarters: '))
    dmes = int(input('How many dimes: '))
    ncks = int(input('How many nickles: '))
    pens = int(input('How many pennies: '))
    coinS = (0.25 * qtrs) + (0.1 * dmes) + (0.05 * ncks) + (0.01 * pens)
    return coinS

def compare_coins(n):
    if coins() > MENU[n]["cost"]:
        change = coins() - MENU[n]["cost"]            #I tried using coinS it is giving me an error
        print( f'Here is your ${change}')
```

Comment: Each time you call `coins()` you'll have to enter your inputs, do `coins = coins()` and then use `coins > MENU[n]["cost"]` and `change = coins - MENU[n]["cost"]`

Comment: *coins = coins()* is not a good idea

Comment: Just write `amount_coins = coins()` and every time you need to access the value returned by `coins()`, you can just use the variable `amount_coins`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is repeating twice because you are calling the coins() function twice, once in the ‘if’ statement condition, and the second time inside the ‘if’ statement. So, the program asks for input twice. You can solve this by storing the value returned by coins() in a variable. Modified code:

```
def coins():
    print("Please insert coins.")
    qtrs = int(input('How many quarters: '))
    dmes = int(input('How many dimes: '))
    ncks = int(input('How many nickles: '))
    pens = int(input('How many pennies: '))
    coinS = (0.25 * qtrs) + (0.1 * dmes) + (0.05 * ncks) + (0.01 * pens)
    return coinS

def compare_coins(n):
    user_coins = coins() #Create a variable to store the value
    if user_coins > MENU[n]["cost"]:
        change = user_coins - MENU[n]["cost"]            
        print( f'Here is your ${change}')
```

Doing this will not require calling the coins() function twice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the value in a temporary variable:

```
def compare_coins(n):
    input_coins = coins()
    if input_coins > MENU[n]["cost"]:
        change = input_coins - MENU[n]["cost"]            #I tried using coinS it is giving me an error
        print( f'Here is your ${change}')
```

Note that this way, coins() will be called every time you want to compare the value, thus prompting the user to input a coin value.

Alternatively, a better solution would be to do object oriented programming: create a class representing your entity which requires coins, and have that class hold a "coin count" which can be modified through class methods.

Comment: Yeah, I want it to be called once with the compare_coins function. Thank you
I would try with OOP later, still a fresh man in python